# Synchronise multiple Mega boards to run multiple servo motors

Tags: arduino, motor, servo

My friend Jules asks:

> The aim is to get as many servo motor controls as possible - looks like the maximum an Arduino will output is 14?

> Digital I/O Pins54 (of which 14 provide PWM output)

I guess then it becomes a software issue to synchronise multiple Mega boards?
- ie 14 x 14 array using 14 boards

Comment: I think when you say "servo-motor", you mean the integrated radio-control-model type of "servo"s? Generally, "servo motor" means the motor used in a PID (or similar) closed-loop servo system. From the title, I thought this question was about implementing multiple simultaneous servo-control-loops on a atmega.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would also go for same route todbot suggested. However since I am a big fan of I2C I am using [SD21 servo controller](http://www.google.com/search?q=sd21+servo+controller) which can drive 21 servos. If you need even more there is [SD84 servo controller](http://www.google.com/search?q=SD84+Servo+Controller) which can drive (you guessed it) 84 servos.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to drive multiple servos, the better route might be to hook a few dedicated servo controllers to a single Arduino.  There are many open source examples of servo controllers out there, but you can also buy fulling built ones.  For instance, here's a [Polulu 8-servo controller](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/208) and a [Pololu 16-servo controller](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/240).  Get a few of those, hook them up to any digital pins of the Arduino and use the SoftSerial library to send commands to them.

Comment: The servo controllers you are recommending are out of date. The new Maestro family of servo controllers is better in every way. http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/12

Answer (score 1):

I use a [SSC-32 Servo Controller](http://www.lynxmotion.com/p-395-ssc-32-servo-controller.aspx) from Lynxmotion. It uses an ATmega8 or ATmega168 and can control up to 32 servos. You can find everything (circuit diagram, firmware) to build it on their page. I built one myself and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other guys, use a dedicated servo controller.

I'm in the process of building my own for my hexapod robot, see [here](http://www.lhexapod.com/cgi-bin/mt/mt-search.cgi?blog%5Fid=1&tag=servo%20controllers&limit=20) source code and schematics available.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use "digital" servos, such as [OpenServo](http://openservo.com/). That way you can drive a dozen or so servos using 2 Arduino pins, and a dozen or so more servos using 2 more pins.